# How can I get the list value from a popup container list using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I used to do the UI spinner in two functionality one is make the increase decrease of the center value and the same time the center list will be appear as select list popup so how could i get the selected list value on center list button.

fiddle is here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daySA/3/)

code from jsfiddle is here

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".bkt-close, .bkt-g1, .bkt-g2, .bkt-g3, .bkt-y1, .bkt-y2, .bkt-y3, .bkt-o1, .bkt-o2, .bkt-o3, .bkt-r").click(function(){
        $("#bkt-toolset").show();
    }),
        $("#bkt-toolset").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#bkt-toolset").hide();
    });
});

$(function(){

    var itemList = [

    ];

    var opts = {
        's1': {decimals:2},
        's2': {stepping: 0.25},
        's3': {currency: '$'},
        's4': {},
        's5': {
            //
            // Two methods of adding external items to the spinner
            //
            // method 1: on initalisation call the add method directly and format html manually
            init: function(e, ui) {
                for (var i=0; i<itemList.length; i++) {
                    ui.add('<a href="'+ itemList[i].url +'" target="_blank">'+ itemList[i].title +'</a>');
                }
            },

            // method 2: use the format and items options in combination
            format: '%(title) <a href="%(url)" target="_blank">&raquo;</a>',
            items: itemList
        }
    };

    for (var n in opts)
        $("#"+n).spinner(opts[n]);

    $("button").click(function(e){
        var ns = $(this).attr('id').match(/(s\d)\-(\w+)$/);
        if (ns != null)
            $('#'+ns[1]).spinner( (ns[2] == 'create') ? opts[ns[1]] : ns[2]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little work on it by updating list items to A, B, C etc and got stuck in some middle. The prob here is: when i select the list item from the tooltip, the spinner list is updated with same value for list items. Here is the jsfiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/daySA/17/

```
        $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".bkt-close, .bkt-g1, .bkt-g2, .bkt-g3, .bkt-y1, .bkt-y2, .bkt-y3, .bkt-o1, .bkt-o2, .bkt-o3, .bkt-r").click(function(){
    $("#bkt-toolset").show();
         $("#bkt-toolset li").live('click', function() {
            var item=   $(this).html();
            //alert(item);
            $("#s1 li").prepend(item);
             $("#s1 li").click(function() {
                     $("#bkt-toolset").show();
                 });
             $("#s2 li").prepend(item);
             $("#s2 li").click(function() {
                     $("#bkt-toolset").show();
                 });
              $("#s3 li").prepend(item);
             $("#s3 li").click(function() {
                     $("#bkt-toolset").show();
                 });

            });
}),
    $("#bkt-toolset").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#bkt-toolset").hide();
});
       });
```

updated html code in table

```
      <table>
<tr>
    <td><div style="height:100px">
   <ul id="s1">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
    </ul>

   <ul id="bkt-toolset">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>
    <ul id="s2">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
     </ul>

      <ul id="bkt-toolset">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><div>
   <ul id="s3">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="bkt-toolset">
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-close"> A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g1">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g2"> C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-g3"> D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y1"> E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y2">F</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-y3">G</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o1">H</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o2"> I</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-o3">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bkt-r">K</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
     </tr>

     </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by simply remembering the spinner state. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/daySA/16/) fiddle out. After you got your value you can now change the selected spinner value easily.

```
var state = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".bkt-close, .bkt-g1, .bkt-g2, .bkt-g3, .bkt-y1, .bkt-y2, .bkt-y3, .bkt-o1, .bkt-o2, .bkt-o3, .bkt-r").click(function(){
        $("#bkt-toolset").show();
            state = state + 1;
            if(state == 2)
            {
                alert($(this).text());
                $("#bkt-toolset").hide(); 
                state = 0;
            }
    }),
        $("#bkt-toolset").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#bkt-toolset").hide();
    });   
});



$(function(){

    var itemList = [

    ];

    var opts = {
        's1': {decimals:2},
        's2': {stepping: 0.25},
        's3': {currency: '$'},
        's4': {},
        's5': {
            //
            // Two methods of adding external items to the spinner
            //
            // method 1: on initalisation call the add method directly and format html manually
            init: function(e, ui) {
                for (var i=0; i<itemList.length; i++) {
                    ui.add('<a href="'+ itemList[i].url +'" target="_blank">'+ itemList[i].title +'</a>');
                }
            },

            // method 2: use the format and items options in combination
            format: '%(title) <a href="%(url)" target="_blank">&raquo;</a>',
            items: itemList
        }
    };

    for (var n in opts)
        $("#"+n).spinner(opts[n]);

    $("button").click(function(e){
        var ns = $(this).attr('id').match(/(s\d)\-(\w+)$/);
        if (ns != null)
            $('#'+ns[1]).spinner( (ns[2] == 'create') ? opts[ns[1]] : ns[2]);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. but issue is unable to see the selected value from the tooltip to button place.

Comment: I know. I thought you only wanted to know how to get the value on click from spinner. Thats why i stopped there.

Comment: updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daySA/18/) with few other issues.After updating the tootip item the spinner list is showing same value for all the list items and tooltip is not appearing if we want to updated the list item again. could be great if you can help me with fix in jsfiddle